# RSpec controller GET #index test is returning an empty ActiveRecord array instead of my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Please excuse my rustiness, first time touching Rails and this project in quite some time.

**Ruby Version:** 2.5.0
**Rails Version:** 5.1.7
**RSpec Version:** 3.9.3
**FactoryBot Version:** 6.2.0

This is my `scripts_controller_spec.rb` file with model creation and the test in question:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ScriptsController, type: :controller do

  userID_1 = User.create!(
    email: 'ueferfrfrf@u1.com',
    password: 'useruser',
    password_confirmation: 'useruser'
  )

  script1 = Script.create!(
    name: 'YWoodcutter',
    skill: 'Woodcutting',
    bot_for: 'TRiBot',
    game_for: 'Oldschool Runescape 07',
    user_id: userID_1.id
  )
  script1.save
  
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "assigns @scripts" do
      get :index
      p script1
      expect(assigns(:scripts)).to eq([script1])
    end
  end
```

When running the tests, the print line above outputs this, as expected:

> #<Script id: 1, name: "YWoodcutter", skill: "Woodcutting", bot_for: "TRiBot", game_for: "Oldschool Runescape 07", user_id: 1, created_at:
> "2021-10-19 08:29:43", updated_at: "2021-10-19 08:29:43">

However, I get this test failure:

> Failures:
>
> 1. ScriptsController GET #index assigns @scripts
>    Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:scripts)).to eq([script1])
>
>    **expected:** [#<Script id: 1, name: "YWoodcutter", skill: "Woodcutting", bot_for: "TRiBot", game_for: "Oldschool Runescape 07",
>    user_id: 1, created_at: "2021-10-19 08:29:43", updated_at: "2021-10-19
>    08:29:43">]
>     
>    **got:** #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
>
>    (compared using ==)

My `scripts_controller.rb` index function looks like so:

```
class ScriptsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @scripts = Script.order(:created_at)
  end
```

Let me know if you need any more info, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Where you create script1 is essential. Please update with the relevant spec code.

Comment: @razvans The script1 creation code is in the same scripts_controller_spec.rb file, and just above the test.

Comment: Plus the controller code with the index action, any filters, etc

Comment: Put the entire spec file then.

Comment: @razvans Updated. Not much more in the script_controller_spec.rb file besides some required lines and empty tests (which I omitted). If you'd like to see the full scripts_controller file, what'd be the  best way to show that? Just put the code in the question, or would a GitHub link be cleaner?

Comment: @AakLak The issue is most probably in the index action query that should normally return the collection. So please add the controller index code if you want to get an answer.

Comment: @borisrorsvort Sure thing, added to bottom of my question.

Comment: @AakLak you need to do `@scripts = Script.all.order(:created_at)` instead

Comment: You can either use `before { }` to populate the DB or add the create of userID_1 and script1 above `get :index`

Comment: They are created at the top of the spec file before any tests, I've updated the OP with that info.

Comment: @razvans Thanks, got some advice on Reddit and they also said my objects are only saved in memory, but not the database. I'd like to accomplish this with let block, but I'm not at all familiar how to do this. Tried a few things but no luck.

Comment: @razvans Figured out my let blocks, myself or the solver will post the solution shortly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rspec test fails due to to redirection to a page for loggin in (Rails + Devise + Cancancan)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802332/rspec-test-fails-due-to-to-redirection-to-a-page-for-loggin-in-rails-devise)

Answer (score 1):

I think the `Script` object is not getting created before calling the `index` action. Because of this, you are getting the empty **ActiveRecord::Relation**. In this situation [let!](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) should fix your problem

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ScriptsController, type: :controller do

  let!(:user_1) do
    User.create!(
      email: 'ueferfrfrf@u1.com',
      password: 'useruser',
      password_confirmation: 'useruser'
    )
  end

  let!(:script1) do
    Script.create!(
      name: 'YWoodcutter',
      skill: 'Woodcutting',
      bot_for: 'TRiBot',
      game_for: 'Oldschool Runescape 07',
      user_id: user_1.id
    )
  end

  describe "GET #index" do
    before { get :index }

    it "assigns @scripts" do
      expect(assigns(:scripts)).to eq([script1])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current code, it seems you were not calling all script.

Using

```
### Controller

@scripts = Script.all.order(:created_at)

### Test

## Should use factories to create the records

  let(:user) do 
    create(:user, email: 'ueferfrfrf@u1.com',
                  password: 'useruser',
                  password_confirmation: 'useruser') 
  end

  let(:script) do 
    create(:script, name: 'YWoodcutter',
                    skill: 'Woodcutting',
                    bot_for: 'TRiBot',
                    game_for: 'Oldschool Runescape 07',
                    user: user) 
  end
```

should fix it.

Comment: Gave this a shot, but unfortunately I'm still experiencing the same results. Made the change to the index method in app/controllers/scripts_controller.rb

Comment: some times a `spring stop` before relaunching the tests helps pick up code changes.

Comment: `Script.order(:created_at)` is the same thing as `Script.all.order(:created_at)`. It's very clear that the OP does not have anything in the DB.

Comment: If he didn’t have anything in db, the puts script would not return an model with an id.

Comment: @borisrorsvort That's what I'm thinking too.

Comment: @borisrorsvort Got some help on Reddit. They said the way I'm doing it only saves the object to memory, but not the database, and I should create my object in a let block. However I'm not familiar with how to do this.

Comment: @borisrorsvort Figured out my let blocks, myself or the solver will post the solution shortly.

Comment: @AakLak I’ve updated the example to use let and factories (since you’re using FactoryBot). Could you validate if that fixes it?